# Fundamental Solution of Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

To find the solutions of Pell's equation $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$, one can look at the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt d$: If $(x, y)$ is a non-trivial solution, then $x \over y$ is a convergent of $\sqrt d$.

The smallest pair $(x,y)$ with $x > y > 0$ found by testing the convergents is called the fundamental solution.

My question is: how can we show that a fundamental solution must exist?

Comment: Google "wikiproofs" for a detailed analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keith Conrad's papers are great:

[Pell Equation I](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn1.pdf): This goes through a number of interesting examples and discussion.

[Pell Equation II](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf): This goes through the theory and proves the existence of the solution.

Of course, these only show that a solution exists. Not that there is a fundamental unit generating all solutions.

Fix $d>0$ a squarefree integer. What are the solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ to the Pell equation $x^2-dy^2=1$? We can rephrase this question as follows: what elements $a+b\sqrt{d} \in K:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ of the order $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ with $\text{Nm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a+b\sqrt{d})=1$? This set is in bijection with the set of solutions of Pell's equation $G:=\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \colon a^2-db^2=1\}$.

Now for any order $R \subseteq K$, $R^\times \cong \mu_R \times \mathbb{Z}^{r+s-1}$, where $\mu_R$ is the set of roots of unity in $R$. Then $R^\times \cong \mu_R \times \mathbb{Z}$. In this case, $G$ is index 1 (all units have norm $1$) or $2$ (there is a unit of norm $-1$) in $R^\times$. Therefore, $G= \pm \langle u \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, this makes use of [Dirichlet's Unit Theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/unittheorem.pdf) applied to $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Since $d>0$, there are two real embeddings and no complex embeddings so that the unit group is of rank $r+s-1=2+0-1=1$ so that there is a single generator, namely the fundamental unit.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you very much! Two questions though: what is an order in this context? What is $Nm$?

Comment: @LukasKofler The Nm is the norm of the elements, see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf for more on the norm. As for an order, think ('sub')lattice, for more see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(ring_theory)

Comment: What you wrote in the paragraph after the hyperlinks is not correct: in Part I there is a proof in Section 5 that all the integral solutions are generated from an integral solution with minimal $y > 0$, *assuming* there is an integral solution with $y > 0$.  (The existence of such a solution is proved in Part II, as you say, using ideas from the log embedding proof of Dirichlet's Unit Theorem in the special case of the ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ .)